# How to count page onload event on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

How to count page onload event on chrome extension? Help me!
And alert(count) onload?

Comment: Welcome to the community! Do you have any code examples you can provide us with so we can better understand what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form what I understand, You could use the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event to detect page loads, more specifically, the "complete" status.

[On page load event in Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862182/on-page-load-event-in-chrome-extensions)

Have a Global variable, increment the same and then show alert.