# Execute automaticaly the script on extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a script that executes  a script, but in my case the script only runs when I click on the icon: I need in my case to automatically run/inject the script when the pages loads.

My code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On page load event in Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862182/on-page-load-event-in-chrome-extensions)

Answer (score 1):

So after looking more closer i found this solution:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
  function ( tabId, changeInfo, tab )
  { 
    if ( changeInfo.status === "complete" )
    {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'inject.js'
    });
  }
});
```